# Firebase Security Rules Emberfire Multiple Access Levels Per Node

Tags: javascript, ember.js, firebase, emberfire

I have two Ember models: a `items` and `comments`. User will post an item, and other users will be able to comment on the items.

**I cannot setup security rules within firebase that allow `name` and `description` to be writable by only the current user, but allow for `comments` to be written to by any logged in user.**

**Item**

```
// app/models/item.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  comments: DS.hasMany('comment'),
  user: DS.belongsTo('user')
})
```

**Comment**

```
// app/models/comment.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  user: DS.belongsTo('user')
  body: DS.attr('string'),
  timestamp: DS.attr('string'),
  item: DS.belongsTo('user')
})
```

**Saving a comment**

```
// app/components/comment-form.js
const comment = this.get('comment');
const item = this.get('item');
// service that tracks the currently logged in user
const currentUser = this.get('sessionManager.user');
comment.set('timestamp', new Date());
comment.set('user', currentUser);

// setup both sides of the relationship
item.get('comments').pushObject(comment);
comment.set('item', item');

// save both
return Ember.RSVP.Promise.all([item.save(), user.save()]);
```

All this works fine. Today, I added security rules in firebase. I only want the currently logged in user to be able to edit an item, but allow any other user to add a comment to any item.

```
"items": {
    ".read": "auth !== null",
    "$item_id": {
        // only the currently logged in user can write to this node
        ".write": "root.child('users/'+data.child('user').val()+'/uid').val() === auth.uid",
        // allow any user to write comments
        "comments": {
            ".write": "auth !== null"
        }
    }
},
```

In the firebase simulator this works. As the user who owns the item I can write to `/items/<item_id>/description`. As a user who does not own the item, I can write to `/items/<item_id>/comments/`, but not to `/items/<item_it>/description`. However it fails within Ember using Emberfire.

My working theory is that when I add a new comment to an item I do not "own", then I call `item.save()` Emberfire tries to write to `/items/<item_id>`.

How can I setup Firebase security rules such that only the user who owns the `item` can update most of its properties, but any user can add a `comment`

**Here is is in the firebase rules simulator:**

Attempt to write to `/items/<item_id>/comments` with a user that does not own this item item, with data

```
{
    "cde": "comment_id"
}
```

will successfully write with the above rules.

However,

Attempt to write to `/items/<item_id>` with a user that does not own this item item, with data

```
{
    "comments": {
        "cde": "comment_id"
    }
}
```

fails.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the `.write` rule you have used the `data` [predefined variable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#predefined_variables) and `data` refers to:

> A [RuleDataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#ruledatasnapshot_methods) representing the data as it existed *before* the attempted operation.

For new items, `data.exists()` will be `false`. To allow users to write new items, you should use `newData`, instead:

```
".write": "root.child('users/' + newData.child('user').val() + '/uid').val() === auth.uid"
```

And, if you want to allow for the deletion of items, you should test for the existence of `newData` and use `data` if it does not exist:

```
".write": "root.child('users/' + (newData.exists() ? newData.child('user').val() : data.child('user').val()) + '/uid').val() === auth.uid"
```

Comment: That's a good point on new data, but it doesn't solve my issue. I updated the original post with more information from the firebase simulator. I think this demonstrates that Emberfire writes to /items when I attempt to save a comment.